# Is it potentially problematic to #include files after user-defined tokens?

Tags: c, header, name-conflict

Due to the way a the preprocessor works, an included header file can be affected by the file including the header. For example, you can may break C just by using:

```
#define printf
#include <stdio.h>
/*  extern int printf(const char *const restrict format, ...);
    Becomes
    extern int (const char *const restrict format, ...);
    And this results in an instant syntax error */
```

However, I am concerned that any random user-defined identifier could potentially break a header file of a particular implementation in a similar way. But one could expect that library header files never break each other because then the C implementation altogether would be broken and thus non-conforming. As such, I have been careful to always keep library headers at the top:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <somelibrary.h>

#define some_macro
typedef some_type some_other_type;
```

And not:

```
#define some_macro
typedef some_type some_other_type;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <somelibrary.h>
```

Because if either libraries happen to contain the tokens `some_macro` or `some_other_type` they could break.

Are these concerns warranted? Or is C required that the number of tokens that can *'break'* library headers be limited in some way to only the user-visible ones defined by the header?

Comment: See [this reference about reserved identifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier#Reserved_identifiers). Note point 4. Any attempt to define (as a macro, function, variable or anything else) an external symbol from the C standard library (like e.g. `printf`) is not allowed and leads to undefined behavior. There are however no such rules for other libraries.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That proves that the first part is UB, but are standard libraries required to behave as though they use no non-reserved identifiers?

Comment: Only the library functions specified in the C specification is covered. Any other "standard" library is not covered. Libraries in general solve this by using names that are unlikely to clash, for example by using library-specific prefixes (for example `mylib_commonname`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's not just library *functions*.  `errno` is a reserved identifier, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am concerned that any random user-defined identifier ...

C has the concept of [reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3)(bolding mine):

> Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its associated subclause, and optionally declares or defines identifiers listed in its associated future library directions subclause and identifiers which are always reserved either for any use or for use as file scope identifiers.

and

> If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or **defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined**.

The identifiers C reserves are identified by the C standard.

Additionally, platforms such as POSIX [reserve additional identifiers](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_02), and Windows does too - [some of which can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/reserved-words?view=msvc-170) - but there are a **lot** more identifiers reserved by Windows.

Note the second quote above, especially the bolded part:

> If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or **defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined**.

Yes, you can and will break your program if you use a reserved identifier.

The fix:  don't do it.

For example, this is a reserved identifier:

`__SOMETHING`.

It starts with a double underscore, so it's a reserved identifier.  Don't do that.

This is also a reserved identifier under POSIX:

`something_t`

It ends with `_t`, which is reserved under POSIX.  Don't do that.  (Lots of people break this one, and sometimes they run into problems later.  Don't rely on your `_t` identifier being collision-safe.)

At file scope, this is a reserved identifier:

`static int _count;`

It starts with an underscore.  That's a reserved identifier at file scope.  Don't to that.  (Same here - lots of programmers break this rule and think they get away with it - they're just lucky.  Don't make luck a necessary condition for **your** code to work properly...)

Lots of programmers use reserved identifiers and don't run into collisions, so they think it's OK to do that.  But they open themselves up to collisions and breakage in the future for no good reasons.

Comment: So if I steer clear of tokens beginning in underscores, or ending in `_t`, I should be fine.

Comment: @user16217248 That's just a **start**.  But any decent compiler, if you turn up the warning level to the highest, will warn you about redefining macros or redeclaring identifiers and that's a good start.  And don't do obvious things like write a `CreateFile()` function on Windows or an `open()` function on a POSIX system.

Comment: To be absolutely safe, I could define my symbols with my own unique namespace, such as `#define user16217248_some_macro`, but that would be quite cumbersome.

Comment: @user16217248 I would consider that best practice.  You can't guarantee that your namespace is "unique" now or in the future.  Longer names are probably more unique but painful to type.  It's easy to remember functions but enum, union, struct and typedef along with enum values and symbolic constants (define) should also be prefixed.

Answer (score 2):

Some libraries conditionally define symbols.  `__POSIX_SOURCE` and `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` are the ones I run into most often but there many others.  There is large, confusing, set of [reserved identifiers (namespaces)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier#Reserved_identifiers) per @Someprogrammerdude, that you you shouldn't use to avoid undefined behavior.  See also [C 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) 7.1.3.   For example the `_` prefix and the `_t` suffix are reserved but I see it in user code often.